# Remove every second row of array multiple times

Tags: python, numpy

So I have several .txt files with over +80.000 rows of data.
As such this might not be much for Python, however, I need to use this data in R where I need a certain package. And over there it takes around 30 sec to load one file - and I have 1200 of these files.

However, the data in these files are rather dense. There is no need to have such small steps, i.e. I want to remove some in order to make the file smaller.

What I'm using now is as follows:

```
np.delete(np.array(data_lines), np.arange(1, np.array(data_lines).size, 2))
```

I make it start at the row index 1, and the remove every second row of the `data_lines` array containing the +80.000 lines of data. However, as you can see, this only reduces the rows with 1/2. And I probably need at least a 1/10 reduction. So in principle I could probably just do some kind of loop to do this, but I was wondering if there was a smarter way to achieve it ?

Comment: Do you have to use numpy?  Are you putting the data in a numpy ndarray just to decimate it? Have you tried a slice `data_lines[::10]`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = np.array(data_lines)[::10]
```

Takes every tenth row of data. No data is copied, the slicing works with view objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should use slicing. In my example array, the values in each row are identical to the row index (0,1,...,79999). I cut out every 10 rows of my 80000 x 1 np array (the number of columns doesn't matter... this would work on an array with more than 1 column). If you want to slice it differently, here's more info on slicing https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

```
import numpy as np


data_lines = np.arange(0,80000).reshape((80000,1))

#
data_lines = data_lines.reshape((80000,1))
data_lines_subset = data_lines[::10]

##data_lines_subset
## array([[    0],
    #    [   10],
    #    [   20],
    #     ..., 
    #    [79970],
    #    [79980],
    #   [79990]])
```

So in your case, if your data_lines array isn't already a np array:

```
data_lines_subset = np.array(data_lines)[::10]
```